# why does 2 back slashes appear in python if I enter a back slash followed by a special character

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python. So just out of curiosity, I wrote the below string in IDLE:
'Happy Birth\^day' and I got the output as 'Happy Birth\\^day'
From where does python add an extra backslash?

Comment: Hey, have edited it now. It came as one even when I typed twice. I need to type 3 backslash to show two. Weird ....

Comment: You don't need a backslash for ^, just write `Happy Birth^day`. Since you wrote \ too which is an escape character so it needs to escaped itself, hence two backslash. Just typing `'Happy Birth\^day'` outputs the raw string, put in inside `print` and it will look as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra backslash is not actually added; it's just added by the `repr()` function to indicate that it's a literal backslash. The Python interpreter uses the `repr()` function (which calls `__repr__()` on the object) when the result of an expression needs to be printed:

```
>>> '\\'
'\\'
>>> print '\\'
\
>>> print '\\'.__repr__()
'\\'
```

So try -

```
print('Happy Birth\^day')
#Happy Birth\^day
```

And it will only print a single backslash.

Comment: Does the repr function is automatically called when we type a string? I thought that repr() will return a string as it is without any extra character. Can you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 0):

That's just because of the representation and the escaping feature of `\`. It doesn't actually include double backslash. It adds it because of the future processes that may be done on the string.

Let't check it using `len` function in python to check whether the second backslash exists or not:

```py
happy_birthday = 'Happy Birth\^day'
```

```py
len(happy_birthday)
>>> 16
```

```py
happy_birthday
>>> 'Happy Birth\\^day' # length is 17!
```

```py
print(happy_birthday)
>>> 'Happy Birth\^day'
```

**Result**

As you see the `len` is considering only one backslash.

So actually it is not adding it. It is the representation mode which shows it like this and it will be correct when you try to use it.

Comment: I understand that '\' is an escape character, but not clear with the sentence "It adds it because of the future processes that may be done on the string."

Comment: It's an escape character and it doesn't do the escaping right after you add it. It store it in itself and when you call it or do anything with string(like replacing, adding etc) it will use the `\` to find out whether the next letter need to escape or not

Comment: This means ideally as in my string there is no escaping required, It should return the string as it is. Without an extra '\'.Why does print returns as it is and writing directly on IDLE does not.